# How to show Modified contents in Applet without resizing

Tags: java, applet

I've created an applet game, but when I modify some of the contents, I need to (maximise or minimise) resize the window to show my modified applet.

even when I add a label, or anything, it needs resizing since I've not used the paint method.(no use of repaint).

Help me with this, how to show modified contents without resizing...

here's a sample code that have same problem.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Appl extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

    Button b = new Button();
    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==b)
        {
            add(new Label("Button clicked"));
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JApplet`) & AWT (e.g. `Button`, `Label`) components without very good reason!  There is no reason to do it here.

Comment: As an aside, why code this game as an applet?  Games are typically better free-floating in a frame.  Launch the frame from a link using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Hi, even if i use Applet instead of Japplet, is there any way to solve this problem? (to make modified things visible).

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you just call the repaint method after the modifications of your content, then it should show up.

Repaint is always implicitly called when you resize the Applet.

Edit: Applying the validate medthod on the Japplet Container works for me in the given example. This also redraws added components, repaint just calls the paint method. try it :-)

Comment: But, i 've not even used paint method. as i did everything in **Actionperformed** methods based on events. so repaint doesn't make sense right. say user gives some input and i change the text of labels. what repaint 'll do if i don't have a paint method?

Comment: the repaint method does nothing.

Comment: I didn't get the solution yet!